# is it possible to dynamically change field name within django-rest-framework serializer?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have `Product` and `ProductCategory` models.

Let's say I have ProductCategory `TV`, which has 
`Sony`, `Samsung` as its products. I also have `MobilePhone` category with `Apple` and `Nokia` as its products. 
Using DRF, I would like to get JSON output using serializers, which is similar to the below:

```
{
    'TV': 
        [
            'Sony': 
                {
                    'price': '$100',
                    'country': 'Japan',
                },
            'Samsung': 
                {
                    'price': '$110',
                    'country': 'Korea',
                }
        ]

    'mobile_phone':
        [
            'Apple': 
                {
                    'price': '$300',
                    'country': 'USA',
                },
            'Nokia': 
                {
                    'price': '$210',
                    'country': 'Finland',
                }
        ]
}
```

The problem here is that the field names`('TV', 'mobile_phone')` in serializer have to be dynamic.

I know I can get the following JSON type

```
{ 
    [
            {   
                'product_category': 'TV',
                'manufacturer: 'Sony',
                'price': '$100',
                'country': 'Japan',
            },
            {
                'product_category': 'TV',
                'manufacturer: 'Samgsung',
                'price': '$110',
                'country': 'Korea',
            }
    ]

    [
            {
                'product_category': 'mobile_phone',
                'manufacturer: 'Samgsung',
                'price': '$300',
                'country': 'USA',
            },
            {
                'product_category': 'mobile_phone',
                'manufacturer: 'Apple',
                'price': '$210',
                'country': 'Finland',
            }
    ]
}
```

with

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    product_category = serializer.CharField()
    manufacturer = serializer.CharField()
    price = serializer.CharField()
    country = serializer.CharField()
```

But the dynamically-changing-field-names is difficult to achieve. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can support this kind of custom format by **overriding `to_representation` of your Serializer and of the default ListSerializer**:

1. First, you **override `to_representation`** of your serializer:

   ```
   class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       # your fields here

       def to_representation(self, obj):
         return {
             obj.manufacturer: {
                'price': obj.price,
                'country': obj.country
             }
         }
   ```

   So that your serialized categories are of this form:

   ```
   {
       'Sony': {
         'price': '$100',
         'country': 'Japan'
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then to prepend the `product_category` in front of your list, you can **use a custom ListSerializer** with a custom `to_representation`:

   ```
   class CategoryListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

       def to_representation(self, data):
           # Group your data entries by category here
           ...
           return {
               'TV': tv_data
               'mobile_phone': mobile_data
           }

   class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       ...
       class Meta:
         list_serializer_class = CategoryListSerializer
   ```

Comment: Wow this is a fantastic answer; easy to understand and very comprehensive at the same time. Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain with such a detail!