# Change ModelSerializer field key with function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a simple Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer for a model that has a field "name".
I want to serialize it so the name is the value and its cleaned name is the key in the following way:

```
"results": [
    {
        "mymodel1" : "My Model 1"
    },
    {
        "mymodel2" : "My Model 2"
    }]
```

I currently have:

```
class ModelSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  keyname = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_model_keyname')
  class Meta:
    model = myModel
    fields = (
      'keyname',
    )
  def get_model_keyname(self,obj):
    keyname = obj.name
    keyname = keyname .lower()
    keyname = keyname .replace(" ", "")
    return keyname
```

which returns:

```
"results": [
    {
        "keyname" : "mymodel1"
    },
    {
        "keyname" : "mymodel2"
    }]
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Does that help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157028/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-field-name-within-django-rest-framework-ser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to dynamically change field name within django-rest-framework serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157028/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-field-name-within-django-rest-framework-ser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class ModelSimpleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        keyname = obj.name.lower().replace(" ", "")
        return {
            keyname: obj.name,
        }
```

Note that this will be read only serializer. But It will meet your requirements

```
objects = myModel.objects.all()

ModelSimpleSerializer(objects.first()).data
# {"mymodel1" : "My Model 1"}

ModelSimpleSerializer(objects, many=True).data
# [{"mymodel1" : "My Model 1"}, {"mymodel2" : "My Model 2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
class ModelSimpleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
      class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields = (
          'name',
        )
      def get_name(self,obj):
        keyname = obj.name
        keyname = keyname .lower()
        keyname = keyname .replace(" ", "")
        return keyname
```

Comment: This returns:    

    "results": [
     {
        "name" : "mymodel1"
      },
      {
        "name" : "mymodel2"
      }]

Comment: I think you want value as a key and key as value I am right?

Comment: I want cleaned name as key and normal name as value.
"results":[{"mymodel1" : "My Model 1"}{"mymodel2" : "My Model 2"}]