# Django rest framework - serializer for dictionary structured payload

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a Serializer for a payload that looks something like this -

```
{
 "2fd08845-9b21-4972-87ed-2e7fd03448c5": {
     "operation": "Create",
     "operationId": "356f6501-a117-4c8d-98ce-dcb4344d481b",
     "user": "superuser",
     "immediate": "true"
 },
 "fe6d0c85-0021-431e-9955-e8e1b1ebc414": {
     "operation": "Create",
     "operationId": "adcedb2f-c751-441f-8108-2c29667ea9cf",
     "user": "employee",
     "immediate": "false"
 }
```

}

I thought of using DictField, but my problem is that there isn't a field name. it's only a dictionary of keys and values.

I tried something like:

```
class UserOperationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    operation = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=["Create", "Delete"])
    operationId = serializers.UUIDField()
    user = serializers.CharField()
    immediate = serializers.BooleanField()

class UserOperationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    test = serializers.DictField(child=RelationshipAuthorizeObjectSerializer())
```

But again, there isn't a 'test' field.

Comment: What is that key, how is it related to the model?

Comment: @Sumithran It's not part of a model. This all Serializer is not related to a model. It's a request that we need to support. Specifically it's some request_id of the sender.

Comment: can you share the current result and a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: This duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157028/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-field-name-within-django-rest-framework-ser

Comment: @KeoniGarner It's a different question. There they wanted to add new field to the response. Here I'm trying to get the payload with 'unkown' fields.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. Why do you want this in a deserialized data structure? Can’t you just accept it as a dict?

Comment: @KeoniGarner I want to validate the input.

Comment: Okay, what field will you associate the key with?

Comment: so, for example, I want the key to be in 'request_id' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I finally solved it was to add a dynamic 'body' field that contains the real payload of the request.

```
class UserOperationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    operation = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=["Create", "Delete"])
    operationId = serializers.UUIDField()
    user = serializers.CharField()
    immediate = serializers.BooleanField() 

class UserOperationsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    body = serializers.DictField(child=UserOperationSerializer())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['data'] = {'body': kwargs['data']}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, in the View, I will use that data as `serializer.validated_data['body']`

That did the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your easiest path forward would be to flatten the payload to the following format:

```json
[
 {
     "request_id": "2fd08845-9b21-4972-87ed-2e7fd03448c5",
     "operation": "Create",
     "operationId": "356f6501-a117-4c8d-98ce-dcb4344d481b",
     "user": "superuser",
     "immediate": "true"
 },
 {
     "request_id": "fe6d0c85-0021-431e-9955-e8e1b1ebc414",
     "operation": "Create",
     "operationId": "adcedb2f-c751-441f-8108-2c29667ea9cf",
     "user": "employee",
     "immediate": "false"
 }
]
```

And then serialize it. Otherwise, you'd be creating custom fields/serializers which is not pretty.

Comment: You're completely right, but the payload was dictated by another service. I did get to some solution. Will publish it soon.